# Invalid conversion from `void *` to `void (*)(void*)`

Tags: c++, pthreads, threadpool

So I'm currently using, or at least trying to write a program that makes use of [this C pthread threadpool library.](https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool)

Of note is the following function in `thpool.h`:

```
int thpool_add_work(threadpool, void (*function_p)(void*), void* arg_p);
```

My code which I'm trying to add a work to is as follows:

```
int testpool(string (&input)[3]){
    // Pass three strings to it. Which we will end up displaying.
    cout << input[0].c_str() << endl;
    cout << input[1].c_str() << endl;
    cout << input[2].c_str() << endl;
    return 1;
}

string input[3];
input[1] = "Hello";
input[2] = "Test";
input[3] = "Happy.";
thpool_add_work(thpool, (void*)testpool, (void*)input);
```

This gives me the following error:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
> main.cpp:167:55: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
>   thpool_add_work(thpool, (void*)testpool, (void*)input);
>                                                        ^
>
> In file included from main.cpp:29:0:
> thpool.h:67:5: note: initializing argument 2 of ‘int thpool_add_work(threadpool, void (*)(void*), void*)’
>  int thpool_add_work(threadpool, void (*function_p)(void*), void* arg_p);
> ```

I'm certain that I'm simply calling the function wrong or something, but can't figure out how exactly to do it properly. So how do I fix it?

**Edit/Update:**

I changed the function to do the following:

```
void testpool(void*){
    // Pass three strings to it. Which we will end up displaying.
    cout << "Hellooooo." << endl;
}
```

And this works fine. Now question is how do I pass this an array of strings so I can access the data as arguments?

Comment: `thpool_add_work` wants a function that takes `void*` as its sole parameter, and returns nothing. `testpool` is not such a function. Write a function that meets the requirements, and you wouldn't need a cast.

Comment: If you do C-style casting in C++ it's usually a sign of you doing something you should not do.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I updated the OP, I'd appreciate it if you can help with that question.

Comment: Just pass `input` as the last parameter to `thpool_add_work`. Within `testpool`, cast its `void*` argument to `string*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thpool_add_work` expects a pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes a single `void*` argument.  Your `testpool` is not such a function.  A pointer to `testpool` would have the type

```
int (*)(string (&)[3])
```

which is quite a bit different than the expected

```
void (*)(void*)
```

If you want to use that function with that library, you will need to change it slightly:

```
void testpool(void* vinput){
    string* input = static_cast<string*>(vinput);
    // Pass three strings to it. Which we will end up displaying.
    cout << input[0].c_str() << endl;
    cout << input[1].c_str() << endl;
    cout << input[2].c_str() << endl;
}
```

Note that I've changed the argument type, added a cast to `string*`, and removed the `return` statement.  Now you can call `thpool_add_work` like this:

```
thpool_add_work(thpool, testpool, input);
```

If you really need that return value, you'll need to go one step further and pass a pointer to some struct:

```
struct TestpoolArgs
{
    string input[3];
    int ret;
};

void testpool(void* vargs){
    TestpoolArgs* args = static_cast<TestpoolArgs*>(vargs);
    // Pass three strings to it. Which we will end up displaying.
    cout << args->input[0].c_str() << endl;
    cout << args->input[1].c_str() << endl;
    cout << args->input[2].c_str() << endl;
    args->ret = 1;
}
```

With this version, your call site would look something like this:

```
TestpoolArgs args;
args.input[0] = "Hello";
args.input[1] = "Test";
args.input[2] = "Happy.";
thpool_add_work(thpool, testpool, &args);
// Wait until testpool runs somehow
int testpool_return_value = args.ret;
```

One last note is that keeping your argument objects alive until an asynchronous call completes could be a challenge.  Declaring them as automatic variables as I've done here means that you have to wait for the asynchronous call to complete before you exit the scope in which they're declared, and you can't really use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` with a C library.  You're likely better off using something like [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) since you're writing C++.

Comment: Your code has a seg fault when I try using the function: `thpool_add_work(thpool, testpool, input);`

Comment: Your original code writes beyond the end of `input`.  Notice that I fixed the indexes in my last code snippet.

Comment: I copy pasted your function exactly and it isn't working. :( Not sure why.

Comment: Any ideas? Even the second version seems to be segfaulting.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer.  You need to make sure all of the parameters you pass are still alive by the time the tread pool gets around to executing your function.  Doing so could be fairly complicated and you may need to ask a new question for help with that.

Comment: So long story short, basically the input string is going out of scope before the thread manages to execute?

Comment: Right.  You'll need to dynamically allocate it and delete it when you're done with it unless you somehow wait for `testpool` to run before you exit the scope in which `input` is declared.  `std::async` can help simplify that since you'll be able to pass around C++ objects instead of just pointers everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
void (*function_p)(void*)
```

means that your function MUST have the return type void and takes a single void pointer as argument. This is not the case for your function.

Comment: So how would I pass the information required if the argument is a void pointer? (Or I'm just thinking stupidly in that regard.)

Comment: @Link But the function pointer argument is *not* a pointer to `void`, it's *not*  a `void *`. It is a pointer to a function which *returns* `void` (i.e. nothing) and take a `void*` as *argument*. A big hint is in the error message where it says "invalid conversion from `void*` to `void (*)(void*)`"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay so I changed it from what it was to: `void testpool(void *)` but now it won't let me pass information to the function?