# Keeping argument objects alive for thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

So I have the code from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180039/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-void-void/) 
And basically it segfaults when I'm trying to use the thread with arguments since they seem to go out of scope/won't work. I need to figure out how to call it and make them stay as I'll be making a lot of work added to the queue. How would I go about this?

Example:

```
void testpool(void* vinput){
    string* input = static_cast<string*>(vinput);
    // Pass three strings to it. Which we will end up displaying.
    cout << input[0].c_str() << endl;
    cout << input[1].c_str() << endl;
    cout << input[2].c_str() << endl;
}

string input[3];
input[1] = "Hello";
input[2] = "Test";
input[3] = "Happy.";
thpool_add_work(thpool, testpool, input);
```

Basically how do I implement this:

> One last note is that keeping your argument objects alive until an asynchronous call completes could be a challenge. Declaring them as automatic variables as I've done here means that you have to wait for the asynchronous call to complete before you exit the scope in which they're declared, and you can't really use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr with a C library. You're likely better off using something like std::async since you're writing C++.

Comment: Passing pointers (like you showed) is one way to grab a handle to variables outside the thread function scope. Indeed in some API's (like Windows) this is paradigmatic. I don't see a question here. Also, smart pointers will require locks to keep them thread safe, which is significantly more work compared to manually managing the resource.

Comment: Checkout these lectures by Herb Sutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA&t=45s

Comment: Off the top, allocate `input` on the heap (as in `string* input = new string[3];` and have the thread function `delete[]` it when done. Also, valid indexes into an array of three elements are 0, 1 and 2. `input[3]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of buffer overrun.